# Merge two heap trees in log(n+m)

Tags: data-structures, merge, tree, heap, time-complexity

How do I merge two heap trees (the kind of the trees is not defined), when the size of one is n and of the other is m in O(log(n+m))?

Comment: merge into a new heap tree?

Comment: Yes, into a new heap tree.

Answer (score 0):

The question is indeed absurd. Even copying a single heap into a new heap tree consumes O(N log N) time. How  can you merge two such trees in only log(N) time complexity. Even in the best case, when the two heaps are identical, the time required to copy the nodes to a new heap tree takes O(N) time atleast.